# Push Notification Failed to connect no error string

Tags: php, iphone, ios, push-notification

I gone through almost all the thread related to this on stackoverflow but not helped me much may be I did not understood well. When I am sending push notification using my php code then it is saying Failed to connect. I have used the same code for many other projects earlier. but this time I am not able to find where the problem is

**PHP CODE**

```
  $status_message="Failure"; 
  $deviceToken = "";
  $userExist=1;
  $message = 'You Recieved a new Notifcation from test';
  $badge = (int)1;
  $sound = 'cow.caf';

  $body = array();
  if($userExist==1) 
  {
      $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);
      $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;
     if(isset($badge)) 
   {
    $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
    }
     else
    {
    $body['aps']['message'] = $message;
    }

   }

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx,'ssl','local_cert','apns-dev.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx,'ssl','verify_peer',false);
    $fp = @stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', 
     $err,$errstr, 60, "STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT", $ctx);
   if (!$fp) 
    {
       print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
       print_r($err);
       return;
    }
  else 
    {
      print "Connection OK\n";
    }
```

**IPhone END**

I am getting failed to connect 0 0. I had a conversation with iphone guys they said their PEM is correct which is another possible reason for this. but they tested at their end and push is coming at their end. they are sure they are right. The PEM file is at correct place at server.

Now comes the server settings, they have enabled tcp 2195,2196

**Server ENd**

```
root@servername [~]# openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
root@servername [~]# iptables -nL | grep 2195
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp spt:2195
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:2195
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:2195
ACCEPT udp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 udp dpt:2195
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:2195
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp spt:2195
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:2195
ACCEPT udp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 udp dpt:2195
root@servername [~]# iptables -nL | grep 2196
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp spt:2196
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:2196
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:2196
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp spt:2196
```

I tried PUTTY to vertify the telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195 and it is connecting from server.

I am not sure where the problem is. I am sure about the code as I have used the same file in 6 projects. My hosting is VPS

Please help

Comment: Are you certain that you are using the right security certificate?

Comment: Yes I am sure I have right PEM certificate. iphone guys tried sending push from their end and it worked. I dont know their way but I saw push coming

Comment: @Sharmaji you are using linux server or windows & use developer certificate.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin I am using linux server. I have never used developer certificate before in my projects of push notification. I have only used PEM file supplied by IPhone. can yo please explain what it is ?

Comment: @Sharmaji, In PEM there are two types of certificates.(1)developer(2)production. Developer used in normal testing & production used when app live on app store.

Comment: @Sharmaji, sent push notification with the help of terminal so you find any error or warnings may be....

Comment: @AdvaitAmin can you please heple me how to send it using terminal. Should I need to use putty and then execute some commands

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26697/discussion-between-advait-amin-and-sharmaji)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to do this using Google APNS library. My earlier code was working fine in 6 projects but when I gone through this documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

I found that  **In addition to the SSL identity (certificate and associated private key) created by the iOS Provisioning Portal or the Mac Developer Certificate Utility, you should also install the Entrust CA (2048) root certificate on your provider** under column
**Problems Connecting to the Push Service**

I downloaded the entrust root certificate from https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_2048_ca.cer and installed/uploaded at the server with pem certificate by iphone developers and it worked.

Please follow this if anyone having the same problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. I read the documentation: should I ask my provider to install the Entrust CA certificate or should I simply copy it near the SSL identity? The CA certificate is the same for all the developers? Thanks